# Sort recources by menuindex modx

Tags: php, sorting, modx, modx-revolution

How to sort recources in modx api. To use in a snippet.
I load the recources with this code.

```
$childIds = $modx->getChildIds($id);

$docs = $modx->getCollection('modResource', array(
    'id:IN' => $childIds
));
```

It get all the recources within the parent `$id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$childIds = $modx->getChildIds($id);

$criteria = $modx->newQuery("modResource");

$criteria->where(array("id:IN" => $childIds));

$criteria->sortBy("menuindex", "ASC");

$docs = $modx->getCollection('modResource', $criteria);
```

[Sortby Docs](http://rtfm.modx.com/xpdo/2.x/class-reference/xpdoquery/xpdoquery.sortby)
[Where Docs](http://rtfm.modx.com/xpdo/2.x/class-reference/xpdoquery/xpdoquery.where)

Answer (score 0):

```
$childIds = $modx->getChildIds($id);
$docs = $modx->getCollection('modResource', array(
    'id:IN' => $childIds
));

$sort = array();

foreach ($docs as $doc){
    array_push($sort, $doc->get('menuindex'));
}

array_multisort($docs, $sort);
```